# Select text files from s3 bucket to read in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, glob

I have text files in an s3 bucket with filenames like this

- file 1 -> bucket/directory/date=2020-05-01/abc2020-05-01T05.37xyzds.txt
- file 2 -> bucket/directory/date=2020-05-01/def2020-05-01T06.37pqrst.txt
- file 3 -> bucket/directory/date=2020-05-01/ghi2020-05-01T07.37lmnop.txt

I need to read files that are written to this directory this hour. For instance, assuming today's date as - 2020-05-01 and time as 7.40 UTC. Then I need to just read **file 3** and skip the rest

I want to read these selected files to an rdd where my processing starts. Right now I am loading all the files into an rdd and filtering it out based on the timestamp column. But this is very time-consuming. My current read statement looks like this.

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://bucket/directory/date=2020-05-01/")
```

Any ideas welcome! Thanks

Comment: Glob is not regex. You are not using regex here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I am not using any regex here. I am currently loading the entire directory and then filtering it out but its time consuming as I have few hundreds of GB's of data in them. I would like to know if there is a workaround for this

Comment: why don't you do like val rdd = if ( your time logic here) sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://bucket/directory/date=2020-05-01/ghi2020-05-01T07.37lmnop.txt") else if (???) sc.wholeTextFiles("...def2020-05-01T06.37pqrst.txt") else etc
This doesn't scale very well tho, but for your case it should work

Comment: if you want something that scales a bit more you could list the s3 directory and build your logic around that